# How do I compile pygame on android tablet?

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried compiling pygame for Android on a PC in both Linux and Windows and its successful but If I try on Android Tablet ,Qpython return error:

> No module called pygame.

While Python for Android in SL4A r5 pygame script returns:

> Object has no attribute 'USEREVENT'

What is the cause?

Comment: do you have the pygame module installed?

Comment: Qpython developers says qpython comes with pygame and they cant even help. So I tried python 4 android but I dont think there is pygame module in it. But where Can I get the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame is a SDL wrapper. I doubted that it is available for the android system, since I never heard of SDL for android.

After a quick search I have found the website of the [pygame subset for android](http://pygame.renpy.org/) which looks like something you are looking for.

The tutorial seems to be complete, so I would suggest looking into this.

Comment: Tried it before, Its not working for me. Thats the same as Python 4 Android. Only works on a PC for me. I have followed that tutorial so many times but Not working on my two Tablets( Sony Xperia z and Techno Phantom N9)

Comment: @ellooku What do you mean by not working? Any messages? Any particular step from the tutorial that did not succeed?

Comment: There tutorial treats using IOS, linux and Win to build pygame app for android and not In android. Compiling python app on my android tablet works except pygame. I dont know how to solve or get it work.  I am still working to fix things.

Comment: Python does not compile, it's an interpreted language, there is no compilation. I'm afraid without the necessary libraries, pygame will not work in python for android.